# Ferrite bead parameters clarifications required

Tags: inductor, emc, emi-filtering, ferrite-bead

I was going through [this document](https://abracon.com/uploads/resources/Ferrite-Beads-White-Paper.pdf) to learn more about ferrite beads.

Regarding **DC bias** in page no 6 you can see the statement given below.

"**Notice that when 300 mA DC bias is used, the impedance at 100 MHz drops from 650 Ω down to approximately 110 Ω.
This means that the noise at this frequency increases by a factor of 135.6 dBµV**"

May I know how they obtained the value of 135.6 dBuV. Can someone please explain the math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

135.6dBµV is approx. 6.026V.  It is not a factor, it is a unit.

It is surely not a typo: 135dB is a massively larger factor than the 5.91 impedance ratio in question.

They are not discussing any particular embedding, or application, and the number doesn't make any sense in relation to an intrinsic property such as thermal noise (which corresponds to element resistance so would decrease instead).

I don't understand what they were getting at, either. Chalk it up to poorly-written appnotes.

Understand that the ferrite bead acts as an element of an impedance divider, and so its attenuation depends on frequency and DC bias; how much, depends on how the divider or network is wired, and the relative values around it.  In other words, the embedding, what circuit it is a part of.